# Skype is getting crashed even after removing the shared.xml

Tags: windows-7, crash, skype

I am also facing the same problem. It crashed even after removing the shared.xml. I tried all possible ways like re-start the machine, re-install the application etc. etc. But, nothing helped. If anyone got a permanent solution for this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

http://skype.com/go/getskype-beta------this is the link to install the latest version from skype that will fix the crash issue that has been occurring for some time now---
If u read many ,many posts thru out this forum it has been advised by both skype users and skype moderators that this latest version of skype that was introduced on November 17th will fix the crashing issue many are experiencing--it is Skype Beta 5.7--and it works--just read the posts---thru out this forum--and also see the link I posted below--------see this link posted from Heartbeat------ -[Go HeartBeat Skype](http://heartbeat.skype.com/2011/12/skype_for_windows_crashing_on.html)

source; Skype